# Ссылки в битриксе на локальной машине

Tags: битрикс

Добрый день! 
Суть проблемы:
Для локальной разработки, перенес сайт на битриксе с продакшена на локальный сервер.
При нажатии на ссылки, сайт перебрасывается с локальной страницы на страницу, которая расположена на продакшене.
Если просто переписать адрес ссылки, то выдает ошибку 404.
Как сделать так, чтобы ссылки перебрасывали на локальную версию сайта?
Просьба сильно не ругаться, если вопрос покажется простым, так как в битриксе я новичок.
Спасибо!

Comment: а в коде как ссылки прописаны? или в настройках? если ссылки прописаны вот примерно так http://product.ru/dsfsdfsf/, то нужно ссылки редактировать и указывать как "/dsfsdfsf/" без прописи домена